# How to install applications in Ubuntu 13.10 running on Android with an lxde desktop GUI?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-13.10

I just recently installed the Ubuntu 13.10   on my Android phone by using complete Linux installer . I am new to Linux , so I wanted to know how to install applications in Ubuntu 13.10 that I am running with a lxde desktop GUI . 
P S : I have terminal emulator and I run the GUI with Android vnc viewer.